# Adding an Appender in Code to Root for Tests - Log4Net

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I am trying to add a custom appender to the `root` logger via code in my test class.  I have configured `log4net` in a wrapper class called `Logging.cs`.

Here is my constructor from the `Logging.cs` class:

```
public Logging(Type type)
{
    XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
    log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));

    var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));

    XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4netConfig["log4net"]);

    log4netLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
    LogManager.GetLogger(type);
}
```

After looking at some examples I coded this into my unfinished test method:

```
[Fact]
public void TestOutput()
{
    var appender = new StringAppender();

    var logger = new Logging(typeof(TestLibrary));

    Hierarchy h = (Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();

    Logger rootLogger = h.Root;
}
```

However, the `GetRepository()` requires a repo name as a `string` which I'm not sure about, and in general I don't know if I'm on the right path or not.

Here is the custom appender:

```
public class StringAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private string message { get; set; }
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;
    }

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and experimentation I found that the `LogManager.GetRepository()` works for me if you pass in `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`

Working code is:

```
// my custom appender
var appender = new StringAppender();

// my logger wrapper class
var logger = new Logging(typeof(TestLibrary));

// hierachy 
Hierarchy h = (Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

// get the root logger
Logger rootLogger = h.Root;

// add the appender
rootLogger.AddAppender(appender);

// set the root logger level
rootLogger.Level = Level.Debug;

// log4net via the wrapper class
logger.Debug("Hello, from TestLibrary Class");
```